# Hibernate add session based parameters

Tags: java, hibernate

How to programmatically add session based settings in hibernate?

For example in SQL server, to prevent String truncation during insert, we can turn off the `ansi_warnings` before we insert a data.

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
insert into table1(col) values('text more than the length of the column');
```

But how to achieve this using hibernate if say we use `getSession().saveOrUpdate()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue using Hibernate Interceptors.
Overriding the `onPrepareStatement`.

```
public class MyClass extends EmptyInterceptor {

     @Override
     public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
         sql = "SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;".concat(sql);
         return super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best generic approach for this is to write your own implementation of `ConnectionProvider`, by inheriting [`ConnectionProviderDelegate`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/testing/jdbc/ConnectionProviderDelegate.html).

And on the `getConnection()` method, you can run a JDBC `Statement` with `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;`

You can see an example of a custom `ConnectionProvider` and how to configure it on this page of the [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/integrationsGuide/html_single/#d5e287)